# Is the sequence converging?

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Consider the sequence x1, x2, x3 ... defined by

Xn={3+(1/n)} (if n is odd) and {4+(1/n)} (if n is even)

As n→∞, the value of the first sequence will be 3 and the second one will be 4. Does this mean that the sequence isn't converging (since the sequence is reaching two different values)? and would I be right to use the "Proof of Cauchy sequence method" as proof of convergence?

The Cauchy Sequence Method being: for all Ɛ > 0 we can find a positive integer (N) such that for all n,m>N the distance between the terms get smaller ǀXn – Xmǀ < Ɛ

Comment: That you can find two subsequences converging to two different values is already proof of non-convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two subsequences converging to different limits is enough (to conclude that the sequence *does not* converge), but if you can't use this or prefer to use the Cauchy criterion, that's possible too.

> The Cauchy Sequence Method being: for all Ɛ > 0 we can find a positive integer (N) such that for all n,m>N the distance between the terms get smaller ǀXn – Xmǀ < Ɛ

**Hint**: for $n$ sufficiently large, you can get the odd terms arbitrary close to $3$ and the even terms arbitrary close to $4$. Get them close enough, to $3$ and $4$ respectively, so that you know (for sure) that the distance between those terms (from there on) will be bigger than some $\varepsilon$.